# I need index function to return blank whenever answer is zero

Tags: excel, indexing

Here's an example of my formula: =INDEX(LIST_Floor_Height_Feet,1). This formula format is used to fill one cell of a table of floor heights for a building, but it's loading zero's into the table's cells above the top landing. My cells for feet are custom formatted as #0' and my cells for inches are custom formatted as # #/#"

Comment: you can use the IF function to get what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in two way. If you want to hide zero values by formatting then use `0;-0;;@` Microsoft documentation [Display or hide zero values.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/display-or-hide-zero-values-3ec7a433-46b8-4516-8085-a00e9e476b03)

If don't want to use formatting then use `IF()` formula like

```
=IF(INDEX(LIST_Floor_Height_Feet,1)=0,"",INDEX(LIST_Floor_Height_Feet,1))
```

Comment: The formula didn't work until I changed the cell formatting to a ? which eliminates the foot tick mark. My table has ft at the top so I really don't need the tick mark. Maybe I'll just reformat the cells and not use the formula. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I ended up needing to use the formula and I think it's working correctly. Thanks again.